# How to start ApiDemos in Android App

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to start the ApiDemos application inside of my Application using an intent.
I created the following intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.example.android.apis/com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos"));
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

When my code calls this intent it catches a `SecurityException` and gives the following detailed message: Requesting code from com.example.android.apis (with uid 10035) to be run in process com.TICE.customtabs (with uid 10036)

Is there any way for me to call ApiDemos app from within my own application?
Will I have to just import all of the ApiDemo code and compile it into my app instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need category LAUNCHER. This is enough:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.setClassName("com.example.android.apis", "com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I realized my real problem is not the intent at all, but an issue with how my app handles starting activities that require running in a separate process.